# storing sessions and concurrency

Tags: php, multithreading, concurrency

I am a little confused on storing sessions with regards to having multiple users logged in at the same time...Does the session key have to be unique or just the value? Like is this ok, if all the $userIds are unique?

```
//if the user logs in:
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = $userId;
```

In testing this it seems like if you have two logged in with separate $userIds at the same time and are trying to enter data to a db, it causes errors. Should the key be a random #? Not worried about security at this point.

Comment: Please add the specific errors you are referring to.

Comment: maybe it just the browser caching but  when I was logged in on as two different users on two different browsers, when I entered a comment on a post, it wasn't updating on the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_SESSION` is stored on the server side and is not a good way to track a user as a session can be terminated after a short period of inactivity. You'd be better off using cookies, if possible.

But to address your specific question, your code should work as the session will almost always be unique.

Comment: Do you say if I as a user open the site two different browsers/computers/devices, the server will share one session between the different calls I (as a user) make? I don't think so!

Comment: no, exactly the opposite. Each computer will have a separate session.

Comment: @Kevin even after updating your answer you're still wrong. As I can open two browsers in the same computer and still have a different sessions. In fact, with PHP I can have different sessions in one single browser if I disable cookies!!!

Answer (score 1):

The $_SESSION vector is part of the [Session management] of PHP:

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data across subsequent accesses

It basically let's you store information in a *per session* fashion, and retrieve that same information in a subsequent call from the same session.

Each session have it's own data set.

PHP uses a cookie or a POST/GET parameter to identify each session and thus determine if the current call is part of a existing session and provide you with the data you stored there in previous calls.

> session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

For more info, take a look at this topics in the manual:

- [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)
- [session_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)
- [session runtime configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php)